# Negative lookahead not matching non-specified node_module paths

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex as follows: https://regex101.com/r/oI3dU5/1/

```
\/(build|node_modules\/(?!@juggle\/resize-observer|fancy-canvas))\/gm
```

`/gm` is just for easy testing - test will actually be line-by-line.

Given the following input (line by line as mentioned):

```
/build/sdgsdg
/dsgdsgsdg/dsgdsg
/node_modules/sdgsdg
/node_modules/sdgsdgsdf/dsg
/node_modules/@juggle/resize-observer
/node_modules/fancy-canvas
```

It should match the first one (/build/) and also any /node_modules/ which do not follow with `@juggle/resize-observer` or `fancy-canvas`. In other words it should match the two `sdgs...` nonsense modules above.

Unfortunately it's only matching `/build` at the moment. How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const reg = /\/build\/|\/node_modules\/(?!(fancy-canvas|@juggle\/resize-observer))/g;

const arr = [
  '/build/sdgsdg',
  '/dsgdsgsdg/dsgdsg',
  '/node_modules/sdgsdg',
  '/node_modules/sdgsdgsdf/dsg',
  '/node_modules/@juggle/resize-observer',
  '/node_modules/fancy-canvas',
  '/node_modules/abcd/fancy-canvas'
]

console.log(arr.map(a => a.match(reg)));
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possibly to ensure that those words come exactly after node_modules (i.e. node_modules/fancy and not node_modules/sdsdg/fancy) rather than anywhere in the string?